# How to pad sequences with variable length in more than 1 dimension in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

Is there any clean way to create a batch of 3D sequences in pytorch? I have 3D sequences with the shape of (sequence_length_lvl1, sequence_length_lvl2, D), the sequences have different values for sequence_length_lvl1 and sequence_length_lvl2 but all of them have the same value for D, and I want to pad these sequences in the first and second dimensions and create a batch of them, but I can't use pytorch pad_sequence function, because it works only if the sequences have variable length in only one dimension. I wanted to ask if anyone knows any clean way to do this?

To be more clear, I provide an example.
Assume the input sequence is something like:

```
input1 = [
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
]

input2 = [
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[6, 6, 6]],
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
]
```

And I want to pad [input1, input2]. The desired output would be:

```
output = [
[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],

[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[6, 6, 6], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [0, 0, 0]]]
]
```

So the desired output has the shape of (2, 3, 3, 3).

Comment: Adding sample input and desired output!!!

Comment: Do always you want `(2,3,3,3)`?

Comment: No it's just an example. the first and second dimension of the inputs can vary but it doesn't have specific predefined value. @I'mahdi

Comment: You can not have these two arrays because have different dimension, try this: `np.array([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]])` you get this warning : `ndarrays with different lengths or shapes)`

Comment: I can have them as nested lists, I don't think that's an issue. @I'mahdi

Comment: It's better that you add your code so that we can run your code.

Comment: Can you reshape to a 1D array, use padding then reshape to the correct structure?

Answer (score 0):

this works with your example, maybe there is a faster way.

```
input1 = [
    [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
    [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
    ]

input2 = [
    [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
    [[6, 6, 6]],
    [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
    ]

len_max = max(len(input1), len(input2))
output_val = [[], []]
no_val = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

for i in range(len_max):
    try:
        a = []
        a = input1[i]
    except Exception:
        a = no_val

    add_empty = 3 - len(a)
    for j in range(add_empty):
        a += [[0, 0, 0]]

    try:
        b = []
        b = input2[i]
    except Exception:
        b = no_val

    add_empty = 3 - len(b)
    for j in range(add_empty):
        b += [[0, 0, 0]]

    output_val[0] += [a]
    output_val[1] += [b]

print('-------------\n', output_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text2array](https://text2array.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library that can perform such padding *no matter how deeply nested the sequences are* (disclaimer: I'm the author). Install with `pip install text2array`, then:

```py
from text2array import Batch

arr = Batch([{'x': input1}, {'x': input2}]).to_array()
print(arr['x'])
```

will print

```
array([[[[1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3]],

        [[4, 4, 4],
         [5, 5, 5],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]]],


       [[[1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3]],

        [[6, 6, 6],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[4, 4, 4],
         [5, 5, 5],
         [0, 0, 0]]]])
```

as desired. The output is a NumPy array, but you can easily convert it to PyTorch tensor with `torch.from_numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the `pytorch` data structure but if they are `list`-like data, you can use my solution.

This function is to fill a missing value in every dimension (i.e., width, height, and depth) with `0` to adjust the dimension to be the same as the max one. *This can be applied to any number of inputs, not just 2*. At first, find the maximum width, maximum height, and maximum depth across all inputs (e.g., `input1` and `input2`). After that, fill a missing cell with `0` for each input and then concatenate them together.

This method doesn't require any additional libraries.

```
def fill_missing_dimension(inputs):
    output = []

    # find max width, height, depth among all inputs
    max_width = max([len(i) for i in inputs])
    max_height = max([len(j) for i in inputs for j in i])
    max_depth = max([len(k) for i in inputs for j in i for k in j])

    print(max_width, max_height, max_depth)

    # fill missing dimension with 0 for all inputs
    for input in inputs:
        for i in range(len(input)):
            for j in range(len(input[i])):
                for k in range(len(input[i][j]), max_depth):
                    input[i][j].append(0)
            for j in range(len(input[i]), max_height):
                input[i].append([0] * max_depth)
        for i in range(len(input), max_width):
            input.append([[0] * max_depth] * max_height)

        # concate all inputs
        output.append(input)

    return output
```

If you think that the code above is too long, below is the shorter and cleaner (list comprehension) version (but hard to read and understand) of the function above:

```
# comprehension version of fill_missing_dimension
def fill_missing_dimension(inputs):
    max_width = max([len(i) for i in inputs])
    max_height = max([len(j) for i in inputs for j in i])
    max_depth = max([len(k) for i in inputs for j in i for k in j])
    return [[[[[input[i][j][k] if k < len(input[i][j]) else 0 for k in range(max_depth)] if j < len(input[i]) else [0] * max_depth for j in range(max_height)] if i < len(input) else [[0] * max_depth] * max_height for i in range(max_width)] for input in inputs]]
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
input1 = [
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
]

input2 = [
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
[[6, 6, 6]],
[[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]]
]

output = fill_missing_dimension([input1, input2])
```

output:

```
> output

[[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
  [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
  [[6, 6, 6], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

If you would like to use the output as a `numpy array`, you can use `np.array()` as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
# convert to numpy array
output = np.array(output)
print(output.shape) # (2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this with pad_sequence, but you have to include an initial for loop to even out the second last dimension.

```
import torch
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence

sequences = [
    [
        torch.Tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]),
        torch.Tensor([[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]])
    ],
    [
        torch.Tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]),
        torch.Tensor([[6, 6, 6]]),
        torch.Tensor([[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]])
    ]
]

padded_sequences = []
# Loop through the sequences for the initial padding
for sequence in sequences:
    padded_sequences.append(pad_sequence(sequence,
                                         batch_first=True,
                                         padding_value=0))

# The shapes for the tensors in padded_sequences are now:
# (2, 3, 3)
# (3, 3, 3)

padded_sequences = pad_sequence(padded_sequences,
                                batch_first=True,
                                padding_value=0)
print(padded_sequences.shape)
print(padded_sequences)
```

This creates the tensors as required, using only a single for loop.

Output:

```
torch.Size([2, 3, 3, 3])
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [2., 2., 2.],
          [3., 3., 3.]],

         [[4., 4., 4.],
          [5., 5., 5.],
          [0., 0., 0.]],

         [[0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.]]],


        [[[1., 1., 1.],
          [2., 2., 2.],
          [3., 3., 3.]],

         [[6., 6., 6.],
          [0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.]],

         [[4., 4., 4.],
          [5., 5., 5.],
          [0., 0., 0.]]]])
```